# Notepad ++ - Find text and replace the number after

Tags: find-and-replace

I'm trying to use Notepad++ to find and replace a lot of random numbers in a long string. I have over 1000 text files with strings like this 
`"movemeto":40`.

How can I replace the numbers following from a random 2 digit to a 3 digit number. For example, `"movemeto":35` to `"movemeto":100`.

I tried to replace `"movemeto":35`, by typing `"movemeto":` replace with `"movemeto":100`, but it comes out as `"movemeto":10035`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exable regex

Replace `"movemeto":\d\d` with `"movemeto":100`

---

What you did before does not work as you want because you never told it to remove the last two digits